# ReacTabs anchor elements should have href defined to allow open in new tab

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like to right click the navigation tab and then open a new tab which transfers the components.

Can you help me to define href in anchor elements to allow open in new tab ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with React Portals. Also there is amazing article for that.

https://hackernoon.com/using-a-react-16-portal-to-do-something-cool-2a2d627b0202